# Creating Your Own Firefox Add-in with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, firefox-addon

I need to develop an add-in (as a bar) that will monitor user browsing data using Mozilla Firefox (priority) and other web browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.).

I have already done this using IE, but I need the same for Mozilla Firefox too. Any idea, if this is possible, and how to integrate Firefox add-in with the ability to interact with my C# code, using VS 2005 or 2008?

Answer (score 3):

The Bad News for you, is that Mozilla Firefox plugins cannot be developed in .NET managed code but the good news is that they can easily be developed with XML, Javascript and CSS. There is a comprehensive tutorial about creating a FireFox Toolbar here:
http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/

Chrome plugins are written using the same combination of XML/HTML, Javascript and CSS but may require the use of browser specific APIs which are not guaranteed to be compatible with the FrieFox APIs. I would suggest starting with the documentation for the [Chrome Labs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/).